# Trigonometric Written Confustion

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I am currently doing trig integration and have come across trig functions which are written as:

cos2(x) or 2cos(x).

I was wondering whether they are the same thing.Or are they just written differently as in the case of  1/tan(x) being the same as cot(x).

**Further clarification:**

Integral ( 4cos^2(x) dx)

Integral ( 2(1 + cos2x) dx

= 2x + sin2x + C

Comment: $\cos(2\pi)\ne2\cos(\pi)$.  I've never seen anything along the lines of $\cos2(x)$, though I have seen $\cos^2(x)=\left[\cos(x)\right]^2$

Comment: Do you means $\cos^2 x$ and $2 \cos x$?

Comment: $2 cos(x)\neq cos(2x) \neq cos^2(x)$

Comment: In my math book, it states --> 2(1+ cos2(x)) dx . By the way, the book is doing trigonometric substitution. I believe the book has used Powers to multiples rule --> cos^2(A) = (cos2A + 1)/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [trigonometric identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formula) that states
$$
    \cos^2 \theta = \frac{1 + \cos 2\theta}{2}
$$
That's what's being employed in your integral

> $$ \int 4\cos^2x\,dx = \int 2 (1+\cos 2x)\,dx = 2x + \sin 2x + C$$

Like Simple Art, I've never seen $\cos 2(x)$ used in a formula.  I would take it to mean $\cos(2x)$, but it could also be, as Emilio suggested, an incorrect transcription of $\cos^2(x)$.  Best avoided, either way.

Comment: Thank-you for clarifying the issue. Now that you have said that,I do believe that the book meant cos(2x). Just a side question, the anti- derivative of cos(Ax) will be sin(Ax) regardless of the value in front?

Comment: The antiderivative of $\cos(Ax)$ is $\frac{1}{A}\sin(Ax)$.  In your example $A=2$, but notice the extra factor of $2$ in the integrand.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos^2(x)$ is an abbreviation for $\bigl(\cos(x)\bigr)^2$ whereas $2\cos(x)$ means $2\cdot\cos(x)$.